# Manually insert metrics to Datadog

Tags: statsd, datadog

I have file full of metrics:

```
response:1|c|#environment:development,region:eu-central-1,version:1.0.15,type:container,rounded:200,exact:200
response.time:980395.597|g|#environment:development,region:eu-central-1,version:1.0.15,type:container
response.size:4632|g|#environment:development,region:eu-central-1,version:1.0.15,type:container
```

I would like to send them (once) to DataDog to create dashboard, because our infrastructure team didn't install DogStatsD agents on our containers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for [Dogstream](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/faq/dogstream/). It allows you to send metrics to datadog from log files (including summarised metrics).

You may need to write a custom parser for any data that is not in the datadog canonical format in order for datadog to recognize the data. Checkout the example [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/faq/dogstream/#example-for-metrics-collecting).